# Process control block in Linux

Tags: linux, struct, process-control

How to extract PCB in linux?
or Is there any kernel module available to read it?

Answer (score 6):

The closest Linux equivalent is the `task_struct`; however, that's only used inside the kernel. It's not exported to userspace.

All information on running processes on Linux is exposed via `procfs`, which is mounted at `/proc`. See [`man proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for details on what's available and where.